# My website pictures loading are slow in the server and failing google mobile testing

Tags: image, web, mobile, loading

My website pictures loading are slow in the server and failing google mobile testing- In google mobile testing pass my website but some of the (18 pictures) are loading slowly. This is basic hosting I am running my website. Can anyone helps on this(suggestion and recommendation). Thanks.

Comment: How big are your pictures? Are they optimized?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No pictures are not optimized? How do I optimized the pictures? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use Photoshop or an online service to optimize your pictures, there are also free optimization services up to certain limits. 
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332689/how-can-i-optimize-all-my-images) is a little bit old, but can quide you in the right direction. You can also have look [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51593/how-to-optimize-images-to-improve-pagespeeds-webpage-loading-times).
Personally I do not have Photoshop and I use [Kraken](https://kraken.io/web-interface) free service.
    The optimization can be lossy or lossless, I prefer lossless (without a visual decrease in quality).